# i want to flex my display but it isn't working . How do I do?

Tags: html, css

this is my index.html

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: Kufam;
}
header{
    display: flexbox;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.logo-container{
    background: #ffaaba;
}
nav{
    background-color: aquamarine;;
}
.cart{
    background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kufam">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <div class="logo-container">
           <img src="./images/Bookstore.jpg" alt="logo">
            <h4 class="logo">Three Dot's</h4>
            <nav>
               <ul class="nav-links">
                   <li><a href="#">Specs</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="cart">
                <img src="./images/Not_Alone.jpg" alt="Not_Alone">
            </div>
        </div>
   </header> 
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want them to go side by side . How?
I'm just a beginner so I can't understand much.
It would be good to get the solution with some explanation
thank you.
I was working on VS Code and using Chrome and Microsoft Edge to run the code

Comment: you set : `flex-direction: column;` reset this value to row ... see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ You need to learn the basics, then we might help you where it becomes unclear to you . flex-direction name quiet well explain its feature ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the display: flex property ONLY applies to the DIRECT children of the flex container In this case you need to apply display flex- not to the header (which has only one child - but to the container that houses all the otgher parts - and then also to the ul as well to get the li's to be flexed.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: Kufam;
}
header{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.logo-container{
    background: #ffaaba;   
    display: flex;
}
nav{
   flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: aquamarine;;
}
.cart{
    background-color: slateblue;
}

.nav-links {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 list-style: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kufam">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <div class="logo-container">
           <img src="./images/Bookstore.jpg" alt="logo">
            <h4 class="logo">Three Dot's</h4>
            <nav>
               <ul class="nav-links">
                   <li><a href="#">Specs</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="cart">
                <img src="./images/Not_Alone.jpg" alt="Not_Alone">
            </div>
        </div>
   </header> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for some reason it is still not working that good in vs code but it is working fine in my codepen.io . the link is codepen.io/antuq/pen/MWyBZXZ. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First: there is no display: flexbox -> should be display: flex

Also, you should use flex-direction: row to make it work.

But it still not enough because it has to be done on the parent element so you should add those to .logo-container instead of header.

EDIT:

The best way to understand flexbox is definitely https://flexboxfroggy.com/ -> you will get it in no time :-)

Comment: for some reason it is still not working that good in vs code but it is working fine in my codepen.io . the link is https://codepen.io/antuq/pen/MWyBZXZ. Thank you .

Comment: I strongly suggest using that link I've sent, after doing it there will be no secrets for you regarding flexbox :)

Comment: thank you but I have already used flexbox froggy and also the grid garden as well as flexbox defence . It's just I haven't really made many projects in the past . Hence, I am lacking in application of concepts. THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
 .nav-links{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
        }
```

You might need to add margin yourself

Answer (score 0):

I have tried explaining the areas which you could improve to obtain the desired layout. Highlighting some key pointers for better understanding the CSS flexbox behavior:

- CSS flexbox behaves as the parent-child relation between items to be kept in flex, when parent element/tag is assigned `display: flex`it executes the flex behavior on it's direct children and not on the children of children, for that you will need to give `display:flex` to the child container.
- The syntax for executing CSS flexbox on an element is `display:flex` only, other values shall not work and in some areas throw a syntax error.
- The `flex-direction` concept works like when you need a side-by-side layout horizontally, the value that works is `row` and when you need a down-by-down layout vertically the value that works is `column`. Hope this throws a light on the concept of CSS Flexbox!

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: Kufam;
}
header{
    /* display: flexbox */ /* syntactical error here display: flex; is the syntax */;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column */ /* in order to get a side-by-side layout value for flex-direction is row and if you want to set layout one below the other then it is column */;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* you could or could not give justify-content attribute as needed */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.logo-container{
    background: #ffaaba;
}
nav{
    background-color: aquamarine;;
}
.cart{
    background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kufam">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <!--<div class="logo-container"> -->
       <!-- flexbox works nicely when given to parent and the parent contains direct children element in it's scope which needs to be flexified, introducing any other child container inside the parent to which flex is gievn will excute flex behaviour on it only and not on the sub children -->
       <div class="logo-container">
           <img src="./images/Bookstore.jpg" alt="logo">
            <h4 class="logo">Three Dot's</h4>
          </div>
            <nav>
               <ul class="nav-links">
                   <li><a href="#">Specs</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="cart">
                <img src="./images/Not_Alone.jpg" alt="Not_Alone">
            </div>
        <!--</div> -->
   </header> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am terribly sorry guys . It was actually my mistake . The div element which is starting right after the **header** should have closed after the **h4** but I accidently used it to cover the entire **header** due to which the problem occured .Once again I apologize for wasting your precious time. I AM REALLY SORRY.